# How to make functions callable with multiple parameters, so instead of f(x)(y) you can do f(x,y)

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

given the following data structure

```
var categories = [
  {_id: 1, order: 0, ancestors: []},
    {_id: 2, order: 0, ancestors: [1]},
    {_id: 3, order: 0, ancestors: [1]},
  {_id: 4, order: 0, ancestors: []},
  {_id: 5, order: 0, ancestors: [4]},
]
```

and the functions

```
var byLevel = R.curry((level) => R.filter(o => o.ancestors.length == level))
var levelZero = byLevel(0);
```

I'd like to be able to call both of these like so :-

```
console.log(byLevel(0,categories));
console.log(levelZero(categories));
```

and get the same result (an array of two categories with ids 1 and 4)

however byLevel returns a function. I can call it like

```
console.log(byLevel(0)(categories));
```

and it does what I want. But if I write byLevel like :-

```
var byLevel = R.curry((level, l) => R.filter(o => o.ancestors.length == level, l))
```

then

```
console.log(byLevel(0,categories));
```

works fine and curries fine. However, it seems not as "clean".

**Question**

Is there a "Ramda" way to make it so I can define the function so that I can do  `f(x,y)` instead of `f(x)(y)`

Comment: you pass to `curry` function with _one_ argument, so `curry` can't make from it function with _two_ arguments. So this variant seems normal `R.curry((level, l) => R.filter(o => o.ancestors.length == level, l))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is all it would take:

```
var byLevel = R.curry((level, categories) => 
    R.filter(o => o.ancestors.length == level, categories)
);
```

If you want to curry a function to allow yourself to supply the parameters that way, you have to have them listed.